# How to get data from the foreign key in joined table in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the details of products in the products table by calling it in the purchase_orders table in laravel5.8.

I try to use inner join but as its result its just values of numbers

```
 $POs = DB::table('purchase_orders')
            ->join('products', 'purchase_orders.prod_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->select('purchase_orders.id as id', 'products.name as name', 'products.cat_id as cat', 'products.size_id as size', 'products.price as price', 'purchase_orders.quant as quant', 'purchase_orders.total as total', 'purchase_orders.created_at as req_date')
            ->orderBy('purchase_orders.id','DESC')
            ->get();
```

Here are the 2 table and the result.

**products table**

[image]

**purchase_orders**

[image]

**result**

[image]

Comment: `its just values of numbers` ... actually, I see the result set you are expecting, more or less.  What is your question?

Comment: i want to get that values of numbers in the sizes table and categories table by calling it in purchase_orders table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a relationship in **PurchaseOrders Model**:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product','id','prod_id');
}
```

You can call the result by:

```
$res = PurchaseOrder::find($id);
foreach($res->products as $product)
{
  echo $product->name;
}
```

Using join:

```
 $POs = DB::table('purchase_orders')
        ->join('products', 'purchase_orders.prod_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->select('products.*','purchase_orders.id as purchase_id','purchase_orders.total','purchase_orders.status')
        ->orderBy('purchase_orders.id','DESC')
        ->get();
```

if you want categories table too, add another join function.

Comment: how can i call it using also a inner join query?

Comment: thank you very much i as you said i just add the categories and sizes table in another join function

Comment: Thanks also to @Jordan Lipana :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a relationship

public function products()

{

return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product','prod_id','id');

}

public function products()

{

return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product','prod_id','id');

}

To out put relationship data is like this

$variable->product->name

or

$variable->product['name']